# Retrieve Parent Data as well by searching in child table in Spring Boot JPA without manual query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, one-to-many

I have three tables

```
hcgapplicationcategory  hcgapplications         hcgapplicationlinks

category_id   int4(PK)  app_id      int4(PK)    app_id      int4(PK)
category_name varchar   category_id int4(PK)    link_id     int4(PK)
                        app_name    varchar     link_name   varchar
                        app_folder  varchar     link_page   varchar
```

`hcgapplications` is a child table of `hcgapplicationcategory`

`hcgapplicationlinks` is a child table of `hcgapplications`

*(I have ignored the irrelevant columns in the table)*

**Entity classes**

For: `hcgapplicationcategory`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="hcgapplicationcategory", schema="gujhc")
public class HcgAppCategoryTable {


    @Id
    @Column(name="category_id")
    private int categoryid;

    @Column(name="category_name")
    private String categoryname;

    @Column(name = "display")
    private char display;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id" , referencedColumnName = "category_id")
    private List<HcgApplications> applications;



    public int getCategoryid() {
        return categoryid;
    }

    public void setCategoryid(int categoryid) {
        this.categoryid = categoryid;
    }

    public String getCategoryname() {
        return categoryname;
    }

    public void setCategoryname(String categoryname) {
        this.categoryname = categoryname;
    }

    public char getDisplay() {
        return display;
    }

    public void setDisplay(char display) {
        this.display = display;
    }

    public List<HcgApplications> getApplications() {
        return applications;
    }

    public void setApplications(List<HcgApplications> applications) {
        this.applications = applications;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "HcgAppCategoryTable [categoryid=" + categoryid + ", categoryname=" + categoryname + ", display="
                + display + ", applications=" + applications + "]";
    }
}
```

For: `hcgapplications`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="hcgapplications", schema="gujhc")
public class HcgApplications implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Id
    @Column(name = "app_id")
    private int appId;


    @Column(name= "category_id")
    private int categoryId;

    @Column(name="app_name")
    private String appName;

    @Column(name="app_folder")
    private String appFolder;

    @Column(name = "display")
    private char display;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "app_id", referencedColumnName = "app_id")
    private List<HcgApplicationlinks> links;

    public int getAppId() {
        return appId;
    }

    public void setAppId(int appId) {
        this.appId = appId;
    }

    public int getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(int categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    public String getAppName() {
        return appName;
    }

    public List<HcgApplicationlinks> getLinks() {
        return links;
    }

    public void setLinks(List<HcgApplicationlinks> links) {
        this.links = links;
    }

    public void setAppName(String appName) {
        this.appName = appName;
    }

    public String getAppFolder() {
        return appFolder;
    }

    public void setAppFolder(String appFolder) {
        this.appFolder = appFolder;
    }

    public char getDisplay() {
        return display;
    }

    public void setDisplay(char display) {
        this.display = display;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "HcgApplications [appId=" + appId + ", categoryId=" + categoryId + ", appName=" + appName
                + ", appFolder=" + appFolder + ", display=" + display + ", links=" + links + "]";
    }

}
```

For: `hcgapplicationlinks`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "hcgapplicationlinks",  schema="gujhc")
public class HcgApplicationlinks {

    @EmbeddedId
    HcgApplicationlinksPK linkspk;


    @Column(name = "link_name")
    private String linkName;

    @Column(name = "link_page")
    private String linkPage;

    @Column(name = "display")
    private char display;



    public HcgApplicationlinksPK getLinkspk() {
        return linkspk;
    }

    public void setLinkspk(HcgApplicationlinksPK linkspk) {
        this.linkspk = linkspk;
    }

    public String getLinkName() {
        return linkName;
    }

    public void setLinkName(String linkName) {
        this.linkName = linkName;
    }

    public String getLinkPage() {
        return linkPage;
    }

    public void setLinkPage(String linkPage) {
        this.linkPage = linkPage;
    }

    public char getDisplay() {
        return display;
    }

    public void setDisplay(char display) {
        this.display = display;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "HcgApplicationlinks [linkspk=" + linkspk + ", linkName=" + linkName + ", linkPage=" + linkPage
                + ", display=" + display + "]";
    }

}
```

IdClass for `hcgapplicationlinks`

```
@Embeddable
public class HcgApplicationlinksPK implements Serializable {


    @Column(name = "link_id")
    private int linkId;

    @Column(name = "app_id")
    private int appId;


    public HcgApplicationlinksPK() {

    }

    public HcgApplicationlinksPK(int linkId, int appId) {
        super();
        this.linkId = linkId;
        this.appId = appId;
    }

    public int getLinkId() {
        return linkId;
    }

    public void setLinkId(int linkId) {
        this.linkId = linkId;
    }

    public int getAppId() {
        return appId;
    }

    public void setAppId(int appId) {
        this.appId = appId;
    }

}
```

Also have created Interface classes for each table. extending `JpaRepository`

I am able to retrieve data by searching in `hcgapplicationcategory` table
with the Dao interface object for  `hcgapplicationcategory` table and using .

```
 categorydao.findAll();
 categorydao.findById(1);
```

I want to search data by the `link_name` in `hcgapplicationlinks` table and get the parent details as well. I want to avoid writing query and retrieve using just JPA functionalities.

I need to search a `link_name` and get `app_id,link_id,link_name,link_page,app_name,app_folder, category_name` (Other fields may or may not be needed.). How can this be done?

- Java: Java 8
- DB: Postgres 9
- Spring Boot: 2.1.7

Comment: Do you want entities as the result or a DTO?

Comment: As entities or Dto, either will do as long as it has the required fields in them.

Comment: In that case you can create a query with joins to the parent table and select the fields. Or don't I understand your question?

Comment: As I have mentioned in my question I don't want to write a query. I want to use JPA repository methods (if its there).